# Devemos "cortar" a mania das perguntas com imagem do código ao invés do código?

Tags: debate

Estou percebendo que algumas perguntas, ao invés de colocarem o código, está sendo colocado uma imagem.

Não sei se alguém poderia considerar isso prejudicial, mas eu costumo copiar o código exatamente como o AP colocou na pergunta para testá-lo e dar uma parecer sobre o problema descrito.

Tomando como exemplo essa pergunta:

- [HTML não executa quando dentro de uma variavel PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136717/html-n%C3%A3o-executa-quando-dentro-de-uma-variavel-php)

Veja também essa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/136579/revisions) que foi revisada.

[image: Imagem que não dá pra entender o código]

Com um pequeno olhar crítico, eu diria que não dá pra entender o que está ali, a não ser que amplie a página.

Qual é a atitude que devemos tomar em relação a isso?

Está tudo bem em o AP fazer isso?

Não seria melhor colocar o código ao invés da imagem, uma vez que o sistema de perguntas permite formatar o código de uma maneira específica e apropriada?

Comment: Claro que sim, na verdade acho que só comentando, já vi usuário experiente fazer isso, outro pra coleção http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/136579/1

Comment: Sim, até porque os códigos nas imagens não são indexados na busca... e por aí vai.

Comment: Olhando essa stacktrack chego a conclusão que uma imagem vale 1000 palavras ou mais :D

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Não é uma questão de cortar a mania. Mas é é bom orientar o usuário a colocar o código. Talvez até dizendo porque isto pode ajudá-lo.

O ponto levantado aqui é importante. Muitas vezes para ajudar precisamos do código fácil para testar e em uma imagem isto não é possível. Sem falar na possível indexação do conteúdo. Eu já deixei de responder várias perguntas por ter só a imagem e eu não poder testar sem ter que digitar todo o código. Em geral eu peço para colocar o código.

Pra mim o [mcve] só se dá mesmo quando o código é postado, com a imagem em raros casos pode-se ajudar.

Claro que se for um *link* para o código, em geral (tem caso que o "mínimo" falha e aí fica complicado), peça para o AP postar o código no site mesmo. Mas você pode fazer isto por ele também se se sentir confortável.

Casos de erros (*stacktrace*), tem situação que a imagem até pode ser melhor do que o texto. Depende.

Tem que analisar o contexto, como sempre. Tem que fazer o que é mais útil e ajudar o bom andamento do site beneficiando a todos.

Comment: Perfeito. Lembrando também que, se a imagem não for um catatau de texto, transcrever o código e substitui-lo na pergunta pela imagem é um bom caminho. Evita que a pergunta fique na dependência de ação de um (provável) novato.

Answer (score 5):

Código ao invés de imagem do código com certeza é bem melhor. Não há dúvidas quanto a isso. Ao contrário do @bigown, não acho que exista situação em que a imagem seria melhor. Imagem é mais fácil pra quem está postando a pergunta, mas é mais complicado pra quem vai responder.

Comment: Mas é exatamente isso, a preguiça de quem ta perguntando. Ai já estamos indo pra outra questão.

Comment: Eu entendi errado, hehehehe.

Comment: Na verdade, eu estou com sono e entendi o contrário. Eu **prefiro** sempre o código também, mas não acho que em todo caso ele seja melhor que a imagem. Há caso e casos.

Comment: Meus amigos o @bigown nunca disse que a imagem seria melhor para código, só para erros é que poderia ser.

Comment: A imagem é boa para demonstrar defeitos visuais como html ou css quebrado, um problema de uma ide/editor de texto em uma situação que não existe. O trabalha de tirar um screenshot e upar é bem maior que selecionar o código copiar, colar e formatar. [Exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4992/91)